# Input box is not full width

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I cannot understand why my input box does not take full width.

I use tailwind css.

```html
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center md:justify-between">
  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
    <div class="icon">ICON</div>
    <div class="brand">BRAND</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex grow">
    <span class="relative flex w-full items-center bg-green-200 p-4">
      <label for="search"></label>
      <div class="icon absolute">ICON</div>
      <input placeholder="WHY NOT FULL WIDTH FOR THIS INPUT BOX?????" class=""
    /></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-row">SECTION-2</div>
</div>
```

If I replace the `input` element with a `div` for example then it is all correct, that `div` takes full width. But for some reason the `input` element does not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Photo from Solution (original --> successfully)

[image: flex containers]
[Link to Example](https://codepen.io/mastersystem321/pen/zYmBOgy)

More information: [How to use "grow" in item of "flex"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow)

### Code

```html
<!-- Flex Container -->
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center md:justify-between">
    <!-- Flex Item List -->
  
    <!-- 1. -->
    <div class="icon">ICON</div>
  
    <!-- 2. -->
    <div class="brand">BRAND</div>
  
    <!-- 3. - fill empty places by "grow" -->
    <!-- Need one-line so we added flex class -> (Sub) Flex Container -->
    <span class="grow bg-green-200 p-4 flex">
        <!-- (Sub) Flex Item List -->

        <!-- 1. -->
        <label for="search"></label>

        <!-- 2. -->
        <div class="icon">ICON</div>

        <!-- 3. -->
        <!-- fill empty places by "grow" -->
        <input placeholder="WHY NOT FULL WIDTH FOR THIS INPUT BOX?????" class="grow" />
    </span>

    <!-- 4. -->
    <div>
      SECTION-2 --> Maybe right Section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: very smart good solution, thanks a lot! I also understand the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

For making that input full width add `class="w-full`" also check if parent span has explicit width specified or defined as block or inline-block in additon to having `w-full` class. Spans have no default width also are not block nor inline-block elements.

Comment: yes, I did that already and saw that that works. But I cannot understand why? The span has now full width and the input element too. Seems something wrong with my html? Does not look neat like this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the input box is contained within a span element with a fixed width set by the `p-4` class, which stands for `padding: 1rem`. This is causing the input box to not take the full width of the parent container.

To make the input box take the full width, you can remove the `p-4` class from the span element and add the `w-full` class to the input element. This will make the input box stretch to fill the available space within its parent container, which has a `flex` class with "grow" utility, indicating that it should grow to fill any remaining space.

Here's an updated version of your code with these changes applied:

```
<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center md:justify-between">
  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
    <div class="icon">ICON</div>
    <div class="brand">BRAND</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex grow">
    <span class="relative flex w-full items-center bg-green-200">
      <label for="search"></label>
      <div class="icon absolute">ICON</div>
      <input placeholder="WHY NOT FULL WIDTH FOR THIS INPUT BOX?????" class="w-full" />
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-row">SECTION-2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But what bothers me is why i need two times `w-full`. Makes me feel as if my html is wrong.

Comment: @Boq7 | You need to use `w-full` twice because you are setting the width of two different elements: the span element and the input element inside it.

Comment: `w-full` is not optimal in `flex`. Use `grow` instead. See my answer here: [Solution with grow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76030397/15167500)

Comment: "I'll edit my answer to include it." (I decided against it) if you don't want to use `w-full` twice, you can use the `flex-1` class instead.

Answer (score -1):

All `div`s have `display: block` by default. Add `display: block` to the input and it will also become full width.

```css
input {
    display: block;
}
```

You can also use the `block` class provided by tailwind